# Double tap gesture fail to update

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to make a popup menu (favorite menu), and I am stuck when I try to update my detail menu popup screen.

Here, when I double-tapped one of my Home() list objects, the popup menu is popup. From that popup menu, the user will select one of the two buttons. However, every time I tap on the list object, the popup menu shows only the first name of the first array. It looks like the Double Tap Gesture is not updated. It stuck in the first array although I tried to tap one a different list object. Please help me how to update my popup screen based on the selected list object. Also, NavigationLink might be the solution, but I don't want to use NavigationLink. I just want to toggle the screen.

All the detailed code examples are as below.

This is my sample array:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DataArray: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let number: Int
    let cities: String
    var name1: String?
    var name2: String?
    var name3: String?
    var name4: String?
}

public struct ListDataArray {
    static var dot = [
    DataArray(number: 1,
        cities: "Baltimore"
        name1: "A",
        name2: "B"),
        
    DataArray(number: 2,
        cities: "Frederick"),
        
    DataArray(number: 3,
        cities: "Catonsville"
        name1: "Aa",
        name2: "Bb",
        name3: "Cc",
        name4: "Dd"),
            
    ]
}
```

This is for my Double Tab Gesture:

```
struct Home: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var tap: Tapping
    var datas: [DataArray] = ListDataArray.dot

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            
            LazyVStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach (data, id: \.id) { data in
                
                    if let data1 = data.name1 {
                        Text(data1)
                    }
                    
                    if let city1 = data.cities {
                        Text(city1)
                    }
                    
                    if let data2 = data.name2 {
                        Text(data2)
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture (count: 2) {
                    self.tap.isDoubleTab = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, this is my target popup menu:

```
struct DetailMenu: View {
    var dataArr = DataArray
    @EnvironmentObject var tap: Tapping
    
    var body: some View {
    
        VStact {
            Text(lyric.name1)
            
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    tap.isDoubleTab = false
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "suit.heart")
                })
                
                Button(action: {
                    tap.isDoubleTab = false
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                })
            }
        }
        
    }
}


struct ContenView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if tap.isDoubleTab {
                DetailMenu(dataArr: ListDataArray.dot[0])
            } else {
                AlphaHome() // This is just another struct
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using boolean isDoubleTab you need optional property to store data of tapped row and use it in menu as an origin, and then reset back to nil when menu is closed.

Comment: Can you provide any example code because I was confused about how to store data in isDoubleTab instead of boolean value? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your main problem here is, you cannot get from your `Home` view to your `DetailMenu` view given "All the detailed code examples..." that you show,

Comment: I ignore the preview for Home() for simplicity. When I run Home() and Double Tap, the Detail menu popup and shows the array of the first name only. The issue is the double-tap gesture doesn't update for another array of names.

Comment: Asperi suggestion is kinda makes sense for me, but I need a boolean value to toggle. Looks like I need a connection between the Home() and the DetailMenu() that can identify what array is double tapped.

Comment: yes it makes sense, but if you don't want to show your code, you are on your own trying to solve this.

Comment: Ohh! This is exactly what I do in my code. I just change the name and shorten my code for simplicity. For example, I reduce the button something like that.

Comment: For example, if I use NavigationLink, I just need to pass DetailMenu(data: dataArr) in the destination. It will solve the problem. But I really don't know how to pass in .onTapGasture.

Comment: sorry mate, I just cannot see how you go from Home view to DetailMenu. How you call it, 
how to receive it, how you process it. There is nothing I can see in Home view to trigger 
DetailMenu view. In addition "Please help me how to update my popup screen based on the selected list" 
what list are you talking about? I just cannot see a list anywhere in your code?
Maybe someone else will have a better understanding of your question, 
"....stuck...update my detail menu popup screen."

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited some of my codes.

Comment: I see your problem now. You declare `Home` with a double tap, but you don't 
use `Home` in your `ContentView` . So it does not get called and there is no `tap` to process.
That should give you a clue on how to fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks @workingdog. Should I use Home() in ContentView?